# sql server--> Insert into a single value which is a primary key as well as Identity() into a column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I wanna insert a records from a column which has a primary key and Is Identity property to another column of another table
.
For example,

I have a table called 'STU' with the following columns:

- SNO (Primary Key, and Identity [i.e. autoincrementing])
- NAME (not null)
- CLASS (not null)
- SECTION (not null)

I have a table called 'MARK' with the following columns:

- MSNO (Foreign Key reference STU (SNO))
- M1 (not null)
- M2 (not null)
- M3 (not null)

  ```
  CREATE TABLE STU (SNO INT CONSTRAINT PK_SNO PRIMARY KEY (SNO), NAME VARCHAR(25), CLASS VARCHAR(20), SECTION CHAR );

  CREATE TABLE MARK(MSNO INT CONSTRAINT FK_MSNO FOREIGN KEY (MSNO) REFERENCES STU(SNO), M1 INT, M2 INT, M3 INT);
  ```

As the title says I am trying to insert into 1 table selecting values from other table.

```
INSERT INTO MARK (MSNO, M1, M2, M3) SELECT SNO FROM STU WHERE SNO = '%', '100','100','100';

INSERT INTO MARK (MSNO, M1, M2, M3) SELECT SNO FROM STU WHERE SNO = '%' values ('100','100','100');
```

Both these insert query is throwing error

Comment: *As the title says I am trying to insert into 1 table selecting values from other table.* `INSERT INTO X (A, B, C) SELECT A, B, C FROM Y`

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: remove the `WHERE` clause in your select statement and move the three values beside `SNO`. `INSERT INTO MARK (MSNO, M1, M2, M3)
SELECT SNO, '100', '100', '100' FROM STU`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MARK (MSNO, M1, M2, M3)
SELECT SNO FROM STU WHERE SNO = '%' values ('100','100','100');
```

I think your intent is:

```
INSERT INTO MARK (MSNO, M1, M2, M3)
SELECT SNO, '100', '100', '100' FROM STU WHERE SNO = '%'
```

The `SELECT` statement describes the data to be inserted. It needs to be a valid `SELECT` statement. Appending `VALUES` won't achieve that.

If you need to visualise what you're going to insert before you insert it, simply run the `SELECT` query first.